# Image encryption with rc4 in android

Tags: java, android, encryption, client-server

I have implemented the rc4 algorithm myself, works like a charm in encrypting and decrypting texts, the problem comes when I try to encrypt/decrypt an image. My output image is always unreadable. No exceptions are thrown. I'm not sure whether its the encryption or decryption that doesn't work, or maybe both. Your help will be appreciated.

```
RC4 Class
```

public class RC4 {

```
private byte[] S = new byte[256];

public RC4 (byte[] key) {

     byte[] T = new byte[256];

    int keylen, j;
    byte t;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

        keylen = key.length;
        S[i] = (byte) i;
        T[i] = key[i % keylen];
    }

    //KSA -  key-scheduling algorithm is used to initialize the permutation in the array "S"
    j = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++)
    {
        j = ((j + S[i] + T[i]) % 256) & 0xFF;

        //swap
        t = S[i];
        S[i] = S[j];
        S[j] = t;
    }
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plaintext)
{
    int j = 0, i = 0, t, k;
    byte temp;
    byte[] pt,ct, s;

    //deep copy
    s = S.clone();

    pt = plaintext;
    ct = new byte[pt.length];
    for (int jj = 0 ; jj < pt.length; jj++)
    {
        i = ((i + 1) % 256) & 0xFF;
        j = ((j + s[i]) % 256) & 0xFF;

        //classic swap
        temp    = s[jj];
        s[jj]   = s[j];
        s[j]    = temp;

        t = ((s[i] + s[j]) % 256) & 0xFF;

        k = s[t];

        ct[jj] = (byte) (k ^ pt[jj]);
    }
    return ct;
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] ciphertext)
{
    return encrypt(ciphertext);
}
```

}

Then my calls:
Server Side

```
Bitmap SelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
            byte[] b = bitmapToByteArray(SelectedImage);

            RC4 rc4 = new RC4(sharedSecret);
            byte[] encrypted = rc4.encrypt(b);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(encrypted);
            objectOutputStream.flush();
```

Client Side

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                byte[] b = (byte[])objectInputStream.readObject();

                RC4 rc4 = new RC4(sharedSecret);
                byte[] decrypted = rc4.decrypt(b);

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decrypted, 0, decrypted.length);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                fos.close();
```

Comment: First, comment out all the RC4 encryption/decryption code and just run a bitmap file through the remaining code to see if the error is outside the RC4 encoding/decoding.  If it is the RC4 then do a byte-by-byte comparison of the input and output files to try and see if you can locate the error.

Comment: The image is successfully transferred though the signature doesn't check out.

Comment: You should probably not be using homebrew RC4 - implementing it poorly has consequences (as broken WEP/TLS illustrates) - whats wrong with the Cipher class or TLS/SSL at the connection level? As it stands why all the bitmap stuff? If you want to encrypt the file at selectedImagePath then just load it into a byte array and encrypt that, on the other end decrypt it and write it directly back to disk.

Comment: I'm aware of those classes but it a requirement that I brew it myself. Let me try that solution, thanx.

Comment: I did as u suggested Alex but unfortunately my problem wasn't solved.

Comment: I think the issue is the way you handle the images yourself. `bitmapToByteArray` seems to output the raw pixels while the `decodeByteArray` actually *decodes a compressed image*, according to the API.

Comment: Thanks Maarten, but do you have a suggestion for me? I'm not sure how exactly I should proceed.

Comment: I guess the problem is with the encryption, coz without encrypting, the image is sent and received properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my error, it was in the encrypt function; misuse of the counter. Following is the corrected code.

```
for (int counter = 0 ; counter < pt.length; counter++)
    {
        i = ((i + 1) % 256) & 0xFF;
        j = ((j + s[i]) % 256) & 0xFF;

        //classic swap
        temp    = s[j];
        s[j]    = s[i];
        s[i]    = temp;

        t = ((s[i] + s[j]) % 256) & 0xFF;

        k = s[t];

        ct[counter] = (byte) (k ^ pt[counter]);
```